# Create Strapi App, no option for mongoDB on custom installation type

Tags: mongodb, strapi

When attempting to create a Strapi App which is connected to a MongoDB cluster and selecting the custom installation, all online tutorials suggest that `"mongodb"` should be one of the options in the dropdown list alongside `"postgres"`, `"mysql"` and `"sqlite"`. However, I am not getting an option for `mongodb`.

[image: only getting the sql options]

I have tried reinstalling `nodejs` which then triggered the reinstall of `create-strapi-app`. I also have `mongoDB` installed locally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strapi has abandoned its support for NoSQL DBs. The MongoDB team might (if at all) write their own connector to MongoDB, however ETA is around July, and stable version ETA is around August.
SQLite is now the default DB. However I believe they recommend using PostgreSQL for production.

Comment: Thankyou. Couldn't seem to find this info anywhere. Could you provide a link to a resource? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, for example Strapi's official blog: https://strapi.io/blog/mongo-db-support-in-strapi-past-present-and-future. And you can find more info at their official forum: https://forum.strapi.io/

Answer (score 5):

try with v3

```
npx create-strapi-app@3.6.8 fileName
```

Is running well with MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me guys,

1. Install strapi locally to your system using `npm i strapi@alpha -g`
2. Run mongodb locally on your system.
3. Use `strapi new <project name>` for creating a new project.
4. Choose your installation type as "custom"

This will avail "Mongo" on the list of supported Databases for Strapi.

Hope this will work for everyone.

Thanks

Reference:

https://strapi.gitee.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/databases.html#mongodb-installation

Comment: This is in alpha. It is not present in the current documentation and seems to be dropped later...